# Cursor in MongoDB doesn't work properly- PYTHON

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that is like the following photo:
[image: MongoDB]

I want to filter MongoDB data by rel. If relation ("rel") is "Synonym" OR "RelatedTo", i want to add the document[surfaceStart] in a variable. After that i want to search in a text file, if this variable is included as a word of this txt. 
My code is the following:

```
f=open(document.txt)
cursor = db.collection.find({"$or": [{"rel": "Synonym"}, {"rel": "RelatedTo"}]})
for document in cursor:
    end = document['surfaceEnd'].encode('utf-8')
    start = document['surfaceStart'].encode('utf-8')
    for line in f:
            for w in words:
                if start == w:
                    print start
                    items = db.collectionNew.find({ 'surfaceEnd': start })
                    if  items.count() > 0:
                        break
                     else:
                        db.collectionNew.insert ({ 'surfaceStart': start,'posStart': posnum, 'negStart': negnum, 'surfaceEnd': end,'posEnd': posnum,'negEnd': negnum, 'rel' : document['rel'], 'findEnd' : 0  })
```

Unfortunately, at the end collectionNew is still empty. I tried to find where is the problem, so i add row `print line`and i realised that the problem starts from the begin. I think that my cursor has a problem. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: Does your first query actually return any results ? If they are all prefix by `/r/` as shown in your screenshot, no data will be returned

Comment: No, it doesnt, but i dont know how to change it, in order to have results :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cursor in MongoDB using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963170/cursor-in-mongodb-using-python)

Comment: Downvote: OP has asked the same question 3 times. This time OP has changed essence of question post answer, leading two different answers.

Comment: `.encode()` is not required, especially if you're inserting the data back into MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all the `rel` field values prefixed by `/r/` ? If yes, you should change your query to this:

```
cursor = db.collection.find({"$or": [{"rel": "/r/Synonym"}, {"rel": "/r/RelatedTo"}]})
```

Comment: yes, all the fields values prefixed by /r/ . i will try it and i will inform you asap!!!! thank you very much

Comment: Now i have another problem with encoding. If i have encoding('utf8') it continues to work but not properly, and if i delete it throws me the following error. startWord = document['surfaceStart'].encode('utf-8') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0):

> If relation ("rel") is "Synonym" OR "RelatedTo",

---

> Does your first query actually return any results ?

---

> No, it doesnt,

Your image shows no columns with the values `Synonym` or `RelatedTo`

**Response to commment:**

The following line is obviously wrong and would produce an error:

```
f=open(document.txt)
```

> Unfortunately, there is an error:
>
> ```
> endWord = document('surfaceEnd').encode('utf-8') 
> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
> ```

Brackets, braces, parentheses.  They are not interchangeable.

```
document('surfaceEnd')
```

should be:

```
document['surfaceEnd']
```

`document` is a python dictionary--not a function.

Comment: its the image. i have a lot of data that include "Synonym and ""relatedTo". Now i have another problem with encoding. If i have encoding('utf8') it continues to work but not properly, and if i delete it throws me the following error.  startWord = document['surfaceStart'].encode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @Nelly Brili, *If i have encoding('utf8') it continues to work but not properly, and if i delete it throws me the following error. `startWord = document['surfaceStart'].encode('utf-8')` AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'*--Can you explain where you deleted encode() in that line of code?

Comment: i delete the `.encode('utf-8')`  and i only have `startWord = document['surfaceStart']`

Comment: @NellyBrili, And what is the error message for that line of code?

Comment: if i delete `.encode('utf-8')` there is no error message. But if i use `print startWord` or `print document['surfaceStart']` it prints nothing, like don;t reading the expression